# Generate subelements in deterministic order with JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, saxparser

I have a class of roughly the following shape:

```
@XmlRootElement("foo")
public class Foo {
    @XmlElement
    public Integer b;

    @XmlElement
    public Integer a;
}
```

I've now noticed that JAXB apparently specifies that it is undefined (and depends on the details of the JVM's reflection implementation) whether a `Foo` gets serialized as `<foo><a>123</a><b>456</b></foo>` or `<foo><b>456</b><a>123</a></foo>`. This makes it difficult to compare outputs in automatic tests that ought to produce the same results each time.

I've tried adding

```
@XmlAccessorOrder(XmlAccessOrder.ALPHABETICAL)
```

to the class. This seemed to work fine at first, but now the unmarshaller refuses to parse data written by the old code *without* this annotation.

Is there a way to get JAXB to *output* subelements in a deterministic order but accept any order in its input?

---

**Edit:** This may not actually be JAXB problem but one of the underlying XML parser being pickier than it should be. The underlying exception I'm getting is

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 59; columnNumber: 16; cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'a'. No child element is expected at this point.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define order with `@XmlType` and `propOrder` as following:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement("foo")
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "a",
    "b"
})
public class Foo {
    @XmlElement
    public Integer b;

    @XmlElement
    public Integer a;
}
```

### EDIT

This is my JAXB configuration:

```
    //Prepare JAXB objects
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
    Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();

    //Create an XMLReader to use with our filter
    XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();

    //Prepare the input, in this case a java.io.File (output)
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(request.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    Reader isr = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
    InputSource is = new InputSource(isr);

    //Create a SAXSource specifying the filter
    SAXSource source = new SAXSource(is);

    //Do unmarshalling
    ret = (Foo) u.unmarshal(source);
```

Comment: Will that allow parsing input where the elements come in a different order?

Comment: I just made the test. Yes, it allows parsing input in different order.

Comment: It doesn't work for me -- I get `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 59; columnNumber: 16; cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'a'. No child element is expected at this point.` Possibly this is not a JAXB problem but depends on the underlying XML parser.

Comment: I have edited my answer. In my case, I have `@XmlAccessorType` annotation and I provided the code that's allow me to parse the `String` that I receive into `XML`.

Comment: x @Mick, are you sure the string you parse has `<b>` before `<a>`? If so, I have no idea why what you're doing is not working for me.

Comment: Yes, I'm very sure.